# TDS is installed but unable to see TDS project in visual studio

Tags: installation, tds

[image][image: Visual studio info][image: TDS registry key]

`TDS` is installed- version in registry-`5.7.0.26`
Visual studio--`vs 2017 professional(15.9.44)`

Comment: Try show hidden files option in VS, if still not there try to add existing project then see

Comment: tried getting latest but showing" incompatible" error  added the screenshot solution explorer as well @GauravAgarwal

Comment: Have you installed the VS2017 version of TDS installation? What you can see if you go to  Help menu in VS2017 and then View Sitecore TDS License?

Comment: @PeterProcházka even after installation of TDS , unable to see TDS in VIsual studio HELP Menu

Comment: Can you try to restart your machine? @KothuriSandhya

Comment: do you have any other VS version installed on your system, if yes try it in there

Comment: done with restart machine..but no luck.. still facing the same@PeterProcházka

Comment: @GauravAgarwal.. i m not sure about compatibility..can u let me know how to check..only one VS version is available

Comment: 1. If your solution already had TDS project setup then check your installed version with what, ideally it should be same or compatible 2. Have you given license key to TDS( it may not be the cause but just want to verify)

Comment: As mentioned by @RinkuJain I had similar issues when the installed version incompatible with other TDS projects, if you are unbale to verify this you temporarily skip the version check 
Navigate to \packages\HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.5.7.0.26 (in your proj folder)
and you may comment this from the HedgehogDevelopment.TDS.targets file

<VerifyTDSVersion TDSIDEVersion="$(TDSIDEVersion)" TDSTaskAssemblyPath="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Tasks.dll" Condition=" 'SkipVersionCheck ' != 'true' and '$(TDSIDEVersion)' != ''" />